# React-Native Geolocation not updating (Genymotion)

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

The GPS location output from the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` won't update based on the location I have set in  Genymotion GPS Simulate menu. This is the code that I used to request for new location:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => console.log("Location: " + JSON.stringify(position)),
  (error) => console.log("Error: " + error),
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 2000}
);
```

The output that I got was (see below), and the timestamp doesn't get updated.

```
Location: {"timestamp":1471229266000,"coords":{"speed":0,"heading":0,"accuracy":1,"longitude":0,"altitude":0,"latitude":0}}
```

I have added GPS Permission in the Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

NOTE: A imperfect workaround for this issue that I am facing is to disable the GPS function on android and enable it back in order for the location to be updated based on what I have entered in the Genymotion

Answer (score 0):

React native getCurrentPosition uses cached position depending on your maximumAge value. Try setting maximumAge to 0